# How to add sliced string value to dataSource array in angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, string, slice

Sliced String

```
dataSource=[]
displayColumns: string[] = []
ngOnInit(): void {
    var ba =  this.QuestionOptions;
    var ab = this.QuestionOptions[0].option_description;
    ab = ab.replace("{",'');
    ab = ab.replace("}",'');
    ab=ab.replace('"row":','');
    ab=ab.replace('"columns":','');
    ab=ab.replace(/'/g, "");
    ab=ab.replace(/"/g,"");
    var aa = ab.split(",");
    var rows = aa[0].split("\\n"); 
    var cols = aa[1].split("\\n");
    
    console.log(aa);
```

I am getting an string as an input into the text box. I have sliced that string so that I can place those new line value as a different value to row and columns. By slicing that string with new lines I am getting output as a different value which I will use in row nd column table cells. What I want as an output is to get that string into this dataSource[] array dynamically without writing the static values.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. First what is the output after you slice the string. second for what are you using the data-source for ? is it for angular material ex-Table view ? If yes then its best to pass an array as  `[datasource] = "datasource"` and you need to create and interface for the datasource for different fields.

Comment: I was entering 3 data and it all got into a 1 string because of that I sliced it and made it save into 3 different fields. Yes dataSource is for table view. this value is shown to an output table. I want to get those string into table view using this datasource array.

Comment: This is how dataSource is called to HTML
```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="w-100" >

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you pass value to your Table for Angular Material. Check out Angular materials docs for more info on how you can further configure the Table in Angular

```
export interface PeriodicElement {
      name: string;
      position: number;
      weight: number;
      symbol: string;
    }
    
    const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
      {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
      {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
      {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
    ];

    displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
      dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
```

In your HTML file

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

Comment: this what your question was rite? if yes please mark this as answer.

Comment: I wanted the dynamic data to the dataSource, but thank you I learned something from your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have got solution to this question.
what I did was assigned and array as below and just called it from below of the string where I am slicing the string which is coming from API

```
dataSource=[]
displayColumns: string[] = []
```

String slice

```
var ab = this.QuestionOptions[0].option_description;
    ab = ab.replace("{",'');
    ab = ab.replace("}",'');
    ab=ab.replace('"row":','');
    ab=ab.replace('"columns":','');
    ab=ab.replace('"drpdown":','')
    ab=ab.replace(/'/g,'');
    ab=ab.replace(/"/g,'');
    ab=ab.replace(/"/g,'');
    var aa = ab.split(',');
    var row = aa[0].split("\\n");
    var cols = aa[1].split("\\n");
    var drop = aa[2].split("\\n");

    this.dataValue = row;
    this.displayColumns=cols;
```